# Выбор отмеченных чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, jquery

На html странице имеется огромное количество чекбоксов, у них нету классов и id. Вопрос слудующий:
Как выбрать сначала первые 4 чекбокса, дальше проверить их (эти 4 чекбокса), отмечены ли они, и после текст отмеченных чекбоксов записать в переменную?
Как это сделать?
Заранее благодарю

Comment: без примера - никак

Comment: Что такое "текст отмеченных чекбоксов"?

Comment: Используйте document.querySelectorAll (или jq) + nth-of-type / nth-child